# Python: workaround for appending to 'int' function

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python beginner running 2.7

I want to have a list which is constantly summed as new values are added to it. However, I keep getting *Attribute Error: 'int' object has no 'append' function*. I understand the basic problem - you can't append to an integer - but would like to find a workaround. Do any of you have a solution?

Simplified version of my code, and then a possible solution I'd like to avoid.

```
my_list = sum([])

def myfunction (i):
    return i 

thing = myfunction (1)
my_list.append(thing)

thing2 = myfunction (2)
my_list.append(thing2)

def function_2 (a,b):
    #function which uses my_list
```

I suppose I could do the following solution, but I would like to avoid it (interferes with existing code).

```
my_list = []
summed_my_list = sum (mylist)

def myfunction (i):
    return i 

thing = myfunction (1)
my_list.append(thing)

thing2 = myfunction (2)
my_list.append(thing2)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "constantly summed as values are added to it"? It sounds like you either want to keep track of both the list and the summed value, or just the summed value - which is it?

Comment: You simply can't have a single variable both be a list and a sum of that list. You're going to have to either create a custom data type, or have two variables floating around.

How does your "disapproved solution" interfere with existing code?

Comment: Only the summed value matters.

Comment: *"Only the summed value matters"* -- then why do you need the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the list the question is trivial, because you simply need

```
total += value
```

at each step.

**Class derived from list**

If you do need both the list and the sum (which autoupdates) you could create a class derived from list such as - which should auto sum when you append to it.

```
class mylist(list):
    tot = 0
    def append(self, value):
        super(mylist, self).append(value)
        self.tot += value
```

**Example usage**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class mylist(list):
  tot = 0
  def append(self, value):
    super(mylist, self).append(value)
    self.tot += value


a = mylist()
a.append(1)
a.append(20)
print a.tot
print a
```

*output:*

```
21
[1,20]
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is your problem:

```
my_list = sum([])
```

This returns the integer `0`. Just initialise your list:

```
my_list = []
```

And append to that.

If you also want to keep a running total, have another variable for the total:

```
my_total = 0

my_total += new_number
```

And have a single method to add new integers to the total and append them to the list.